# CakePHP can't save into Postgres database, but with successful return

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

Does anyone encounter this issue before?

In CakePHP, I'm having this.

```
    $this->loadModel('BankBalance');
    $data = array("BankBalance"=> array(bla bla bla...);
    $this->BankBalance->save($data);
    $log = $this->BankBalance->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false); debug($log);
```

and the debug return me this

```
array(
'log' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'query' => 'BEGIN',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => null,
        'numRows' => null,
        'took' => null
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'query' => 'INSERT INTO bla bla bla...)',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 7
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'query' => 'COMMIT',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 7
    )
),
'count' => (int) 3,
'time' => (float) 14)
```

In actual fact, the row was not inserted despite successful message returned. But if I copied the generated SQL and run it, it does really INSERT into the table. 
I've tried to use saveMany as well, it didn't do the INSERTion but still, return me successful message.

There is no error log in CakePHP. updateAll is working fine for the UPDATE. And now I'm looking for the sql INSERT

I can't even do the ->save into a simple table with single field(character varying(50)), no triggers, nothing. Return me success message but no physical data insert into the table.

Comment: Try to validate data first, there might be some error.

Comment: @urfusion the data is clean. as i could copy the generated SQL, then paste into pgAdmin and execute it, no problem.

Comment: By validate I mean validate by cakephp model validation using `set` method

Comment: @urfusion

                $this->BankBalance->set($data);
  if ($this->BankBalance->validates()) {
    debug("a");
  } else {
    // didn't validate logic
    $errors = $this->BankBalance->validationErrors;
    debug($errors);
  }


It always go to the debug("a"), which mean no error.. Any further advise?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data, you need to create a new one by put

```
$this->BankBalance->create();
```

anywhere before(best at the beginning)

```
$this->BankBalance->save($data);
```

and put

```
if($this->BankBalance->save($data)){
    $log = $this->BankBalance->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
    debug($log);
}
```

instead of

```
$this->BankBalance->save($data);
$log = $this->BankBalance->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false); debug($log);
```

to know if save successfully

Comment: The proposed solution is more towards proper structure of the codes. It is still not working, have you tried to run in your environment? I've been working with CakePHP & MYSQL for 5 years, but this is my first time using CakePHP with Postgres as DB

Comment: sorry I didn't realized it was postgresql. Try `$this->BankBalance->buildColumn();` instead of `$this->BankBalance->create();`

Comment: I'm having this error message "Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "buildColumn" LINE 1: buildColumn ^" after change from ->create to ->buildColumn().

Comment: Is this buildColumn() represent save into postgres db?

Answer (score 0):

`save($entity)` expects entity, you provide an array:

```
$this->loadModel('BankBalance');
$data = array("BankBalance"=> array(bla bla bla...);
$entity = $this->BankBalance->newEntity($data);
$result = $this->BankBalance->save($entity);
```